# Cross browser testing on Selenium using NetBeans

Tags: java, xml, selenium, netbeans

I've been working with Selenium WebDriver for about 2 weeks now. I came across some tutorials on Youtube on how to test Selenium on multiple browsers. But, most of the tutorials are run using Eclipse. The video shows implementing an XML file and running the XML file. I tried doing that on NetBeans, but it doesn't seem to run.

Is there a way to run the XML file or is there another way that I can run my script on multiple browsers using NetBeans?

This is my java file:

```
public class hotel_tree_of_life
{
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlreporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\Selenium\\report_v3.html");
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    ExtentTest test;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setup(String browser)
    {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();  

        }
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe"); 
            driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        }
        else
        { 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\edgedriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlreporter);

        jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

        driver.get("https://www.hoteltreeoflife.com/reservation/"); 
    }
}
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
    <test name="Test"> 
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="extent_v3.hotel_tree_of_life" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="IETest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="edge" />
        <classes>
            <class name="extent_v3.hotel_tree_of_life" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XML file is test runner file, to be more specific **TestNG**, make sure you use TestNG and not JUnit (usually default test runner in most IDE's)

Comment: Yeah, I am using TestNG. But, I cannot seem to run the XML file